# Kinect V.2 saving stream to binary file and replaying it

Tags: c#, kinect, depth

Apologies if this question has been asked before, I could not find it.
I'm trying to save the depth stream from a Xbox One Kinect camera (using the `sdk 2.0`) to a .bin file using `C#`. I am using the sample code from `DepthBasics-WPF`, and I'd like to save the stream to a file,read it afterwards before doing further progress.
After saving the stream, I would like to replay it (in another part of the application) by reading it from the file and passing it to an eventhandler (e.g `Reader_FrameReady`).

I found a tutorial that helped me to save the stream, but it's outdated (`sdk 1.8`) and a lot of things have changed since.
Here is an example of my code so far, with the saving part only. Is it enough if I only save the proprieties/parameters shown in the code below?

```
class DepthRecorder
{
    DateTime referenceTime;
    readonly BinaryWriter writer;

    internal DepthRecorder(BinaryWriter writer)
    {
        this.writer = writer;
        referenceTime = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public void Record(DepthFrame frame)
    {
        // Header
        writer.Write(2);//depth data
        // Data
        TimeSpan timeSpan = DateTime.Now.Subtract(referenceTime);
        referenceTime = DateTime.Now;

        writer.Write((long)timeSpan.TotalMilliseconds);
        writer.Write(frame.FrameDescription.BytesPerPixel);
        writer.Write(frame.FrameDescription.Width);
        writer.Write(frame.FrameDescription.Height);

        // Bytes
        ushort[] ushorts = new ushort[frame.FrameDescription.LengthInPixels];
        frame.CopyFrameDataToArray(ushorts);
        writer.Write(ushorts.Length);
        foreach (short s in ushorts)
        {
            writer.Write(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Even documentation/tutorials with the sdk 2.0 would be really handy, since the MSDN one seems kind of raw and hard to navigate through.

Comment: Do you want to save video stream or all streams? Have you used Kinect studio? it saves streams in .xef file but it's encoding algorithm isn't revealed yet.

Comment: What a .bin file is?

Comment: Yes, I tried using Kinect Studio, but I have to do the same thing from code.. And I only need to save the Depth Stream.